# jQuery-UI Draggables in IE8 fail after first `return false;`

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to set up a specific area to allow dragging. At the moment, I'm setting it up as follows:

```
dragthis.draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

The `return false;` works as expected for IE8, but afterward dragging doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the containment options instead to constrain movement?

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

Comment: No, because i need to do some other calculations too, while dragging.